# How to create background for TextView via XML file in Drawable folder

Tags: java, android

Below is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The thick black square line is the outline of the dimension of the `TextView`.  The area around the rounded-corner square needs to be completely transparent so the background can show through from the layout that the `TextView` is laying on top of.

I think this is achieved through creating a file in the `Drawable` folder and the file needs to utilize commands such as `stroke`, `solid`, `corners` and things similar but I am not sure where to go from there.  I am having trouble finding any complete and thorough tutorial that helps with this also.  Below is where I started but could not get much further.

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

But this is not close to my above picture.  My question is how can I adjust the code above to get to my desired picture?

Answer (score 1):

Try this shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#000000" />
    <corners 
      android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
      android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Then you set your text field like that:

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/roundedView"
 />
```

Comment: That looks great.  It rounded the corners nicely and behind the rounded corners are the background that I wanted to show.  But, is there any way to make it so there is the border around the whole TextView?

Comment: Like the black border on your image?

Comment: No, like the 3dp wide border around the whole TextView in the image.  That way there is a border around the whole TextView.

Comment: Try to add margin on your TextView

Answer (score 0):

For this background you have to use the 'layer-list'. Like:

rounded_shapes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <solid android:color="#f46721" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Apply this drawable(means layer_list xml) to the background of TextView.